# How to show slider with caption?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

JQuery

```
$('.slider').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    slides: '>a',
    swipe: true,
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    prev:'.btn_prev',
    next:'.btn_next',
    timeout: 5000,
    speed: 1000,
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider">

    <a class="cycle-slide">
        <img src="slide07.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
            skdfksfksdfksdhfvdkvdk
        </div>
    </a>


    <a class="cycle-slide">
        <img src="slide07.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
            skdfksfksdfksdhfvdkvdk
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="cycle-slide">
        <img src="slide07.jpg">

        <div class="caption">
            skdfksfksdfksdhfvdkvdk
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: 100%
    width: 300px;
}
```

Wanted to have caption in black background with opacity on the right side with description. But caption does not appear at all. Have been struggling to have the caption appear on the image on right side.

Checked demo on cycle website and it shows caption if use alt and it appears on the bottom. Not sure why captions are not working on right side.

**Update: Issue arrows - next and prev**

```
 <a href="#" class="btn_prev"></a>
          <a href="#" class="btn_next"></a>
```

How to make them stay on all of the slides' caption area so it slides together?

Comment: What if you set .cycle-slide to display: block and position: relative? What's the example that you're using from jQuery Cycle? Thx

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ydo7ubr0/

Answer (score 0):

As per [caption demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caption.php)

> You can add a simple, default caption by including an empty div in your 
>       slideshow container with the class cycle-caption

You are using a class called `caption` instead of `cycle-caption` as per documentation.

Answer (score 0):

see the css below:

CSS

```
.caption {
position: relative;
top: 0;
right: 0;
color:#fff;
background: #000;
opacity: 0.7;
height: 100%
width: 300px;
display:block;
text-align:right;
}
```